# Ubuntu 12.04 - touchpad not working

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

I installed the 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP Pavilion laptop, but the touchpad isn't working. I've already tried reinstalling, so that won't fix it.

I've managed to get the terminal open using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but I don't know what I'm doing. So can someone help me with this?

Comment: I have had success with HP Laptops in the past using the reset procedure described in this article: [HP Pavilion TouchPad not working](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/HP-Pavilion-TouchPad-not-working/td-p/1340233) What model of laptop are you using? Are you sure you have a Synaptics Touchpad?

Comment: the same thing happened to me while i accidentally interrupted and update/install after i reboot, my touchpad (Aspire E1-531) stopped working. i followed the above instructions sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this command in terminal (found in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1971196 this thread)

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Does your laptop by any chance have a built in keystroke (button press, combination of buttons to press etc) to enable/disable the touchpad?

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work. It claims it's already the newest one.

It doesn't have any keystrokes that can disable the touchpad. I've found external mouses aren't working either though

Comment: same problem for me with my old dell inspiron 6000 (even if correctly enabled) :/ what returns `xinput` in the terminal ? also, have a look at systems settings > mouse and touchpad to see if it is correctly enabled

Answer (score 1):

Try Fn and "F" keys - just don't hit any you know do something you don't want (like turn off your wireless).  Someone else was trying to hook my laptop up to a TV, and accidentally hit Fn + F9.  The Mousepad control still showed it as enabled; restarting, disabling then enabling - nothing worked until I hit the right hotkeys.

Comment: Helped me a lot, made same Fn + F9 hit by mistake, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

The following steps in the article solved my problem like a charm:

[Is Your Laptop Touchpad Not Working After Upgrading To Ubuntu 11.10? Try to Enable it with Dconf-Tools](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/11/is-your-laptop-touchpad-not-working.html)

---

Open the terminal and install `dconf-tools` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Via the Unity Dash, launch `dconf` Editor

Navigate now to this path:

```
org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals > touchpad
```

On the right pane of the window, check on `touchpad-enabled` to enable it.

After you finish close the editor, no reboot or logoff is required.